Add metadata to file when uploading to Google Drive
Described a REST client for file upload
@HttpExchange("${google-drive.url}")
public interface GDriveClient {

    @PostExchange("/upload/drive/v3/files")
    ResponseEntity<GDataOutput> uploadFile(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String authorization,
                                           @RequestBody byte[] data);
}

It works, but the file is downloaded to the root and with a fixed name Untitled
I want it to download to a specific folder and have a name generated in the application
One example shows the following transmission format
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer ${r}" \
    -F "metadata={name :'test.txt'};type=application/json;charset=UTF-8" \
    -F "file=@test.txt;type=text/plain" \
    https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart

But I don't understand how I can transfer such a format.
Who has encountered this, tell me how I can transfer metainformation

You need to add the parents to the body in order to set the directory.
// File's metadata.
File fileMetadata = new File();
fileMetadata.setName("My Report");
fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");
fileMetadata.setParents(directory id);

